# Push objects into an array

Tags: typescript

I have an inventory class. In that class I have 2 functions that have an array of items in them. I want to grab all the items from both arrays and push them together into a singel array which I then use to filter out items.

```
class Inventory {

    private _lions = [];
    private _wolves = [];
    private _allAnimals: Array<any>  = [];

    getAllLions(): void {
        const lions: Array<ILion> = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Joffrey', gender: Gender.male, age: 20, price: 220, species: Species.lion, vertrabrates: true, warmBlood: true, hair: 'Golden', runningSpeed: 30, makeSound() { } },
            { id: 2, name: 'Tommen', gender: Gender.male, age: 18, price: 230, species: Species.lion, vertrabrates: true, warmBlood: true, hair: 'Golden', runningSpeed: 30, makeSound() { } },
            { id: 3, name: 'Marcella', gender: Gender.female, age: 24, price: 180, species: Species.lion, vertrabrates: true, warmBlood: true, hair: 'Golden', runningSpeed: 30, makeSound() { } },
        ];

        for (let lion of lions) {
            this._lions.push(lion);
        }        
    }

    getAllWolves(): void {
        const wolves: Array<IWolf> = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Jon', gender: Gender.male, price: 130, species: Species.wolf, age: 13, vertrabrates: true, warmBlood: true, hair: 'Grey', runningSpeed: 30, makeSound() { } },
            { id: 2, name: 'Robb', gender: Gender.male, price: 80, species: Species.wolf, age: 18, vertrabrates: true, warmBlood: true, hair: 'Black', runningSpeed: 30, makeSound() { } },
            { id: 3, name: 'Sansa', gender: Gender.female, price: 10, species: Species.wolf, age: 35, vertrabrates: true, warmBlood: true, hair: 'Grey', runningSpeed: 30, makeSound() { } },
            { id: 4, name: 'Arya', gender: Gender.female, price: 190, species: Species.wolf, age: 8, vertrabrates: true, warmBlood: true, hair: 'White', runningSpeed: 30, makeSound() { } },
        ];

        for (let wolf of wolves) {
            this._wolves.push(wolf);
        }
    }

    getAllAnimals(): void {
        this._allAnimals = this._lions.concat(this._wolves);
    };

    findByTemplate(template: any): Array<any>  {
        return this._allAnimals.filter(animal => {
            return Object.keys(template).every(propertyName => animal[propertyName] === template[propertyName]);
        });
    }
}
```

Doing to for loop on the array for lions and wolves works, but I would rather push the whole array in the  field. But then I'm pushing an array inside an array which causes problems with the filter function.

Is it possible to push the lion array into the _lion field witout inserting an array in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the spread operator you can do it using push, like:

```
this._wolves.push(...wolves);
```

Comment: Do you think there's a prefered way to do this? Performance-wise?

Comment: I do not know performance wise, but push _adds_ the items to the array, while concat _returns a new array_. So it might depend if you want to keep your source array as it is or change it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that:

```
this._wolves = this._wolves.concat(wolves);
```

Is a good solution, with concat it grabs the all the objects from an array to merge them with another array. But if you don't do that it just returns the objects from the current array.